# How to share components between modules with lazy loading

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I'm loading my modules with lazy load. I'm in a situation where I need to use one form of a module in another module.

For example, there is the product module and the brand module. Both are loaded in lazy load. But I wanted to make it possible for the user to register the brands within the product form. But my question is that both modules are loaded lazily.

Do I really need to fully load the two modules? Or could I just load only the required component?

**my loading lazy load:**

```
const productRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'product',
    loadChildren: 'app/admin/product/product.module#ProductModule',
    canLoad: [AuthGuard]
  }
];

const brandRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'brand',
    loadChildren: 'app/admin/brand/brand.module#BrandModule',
    canLoad: [AuthGuard]
  }
];
```

my component:

```
....

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exemplo">Create Name Product</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)]="Product.name" #name="ngModel" >
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exemplo">Create Brand</label>
    <brand-form-component></brand-form-component>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

I created the shared module:

```
import { NgModule }            from '@angular/core';

import { FormComponent as 
    FormBrandComponent }      from '../../brand/brand-form/form.component'

@NgModule({
  imports:      [  ],
  declarations: [ FormBrandComponent ],
  providers:    [ FormBrandComponent ],
  exports:      [ FormBrandComponent ],
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

And I imported in the other modules:

Brand Module

```
import { SharedModule }from '../shared/shared.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ SharedModule, DialogModule, GrowlModule, Ng2PaginationModule, BrandRouting ],
  declarations: [ BrandComponent, ListComponent ],
  providers:[ BrandService ]
})
export class BrandModule {}
```

product Module

```
import { SharedModule }from './shared/shared.module';


@NgModule({
  imports: [ SharedModule, CurrencyMaskModule, DragulaModule, GrowlModule, DialogModule, Ng2PaginationModule, productRouting, ReactiveFormsModule ],
  declarations: [ ProductComponent, FormComponent, ListComponent ],
  providers:[ FormComponent, ProductService, BreadService, MarcaService, GradeService ]
})
export class ProductModule { }
```

But is giving the following error:

[image]

Comment: a few things: 1. your first shared module has FormBrandComponent as a provider - i assume that's a typo - FormBrandComponent should be in your declarables, not your providers. 2. in your shared module, you need to import whatever modules your shared module's components are using (for eg the FormsModule from @angular/forms, CommonModule etc. 3. A component should only be declared on a single module - you're declaring your FormComponent in two different modules - shared and product....

Comment: my point about introducing the shared module was that you obviously have some code that's being used in both modules, so conceptually, there's some overlap in functionality between the two feature modules that you havent' explicitly recognised. So, i'm saying move that shared functionality completely to a new module and let the other two feature modules use the functionality from there. in other words, it's probably a good idea to let your folder structure also reflect that shared dependency rather than creating your shared module by referencing pieces of your brand module

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The current implementation of lazy loading is on the module level, and it's all or nothing. If you need to share components between the two (which is what this sounds like), then it's possible you have a hidden shared module that you haven't yet completely identified. So, it's quite possible that you should be creating a new module to house those shared components/services and having that module be imported into the other two lazy loaded modules.

It is your choice whether that new module would be lazy or eagerly loaded - either would work. (Since it is a dependency of both the product and brand modules, once either is loaded, the new module would also get loaded).

Comment: I should create a shared module that will be imported by the two other modules, and what do I put inside the shared module? Only the form component common to both modules?

Comment: you would put whatever components/services are being used by both modules.  When building feature modules (which is what your product and brand modules appear to be), the features should be relatively self contained. And if there are things (components, directives, pipes, services) that need to be used multiple feature modules,  it's usually an indication that there's some shared module that you could extract from the two. So all i'm saying is instead of sharing items implicitly, make it explicit by creating a module containing whatever is shared

Comment: I understand. What you say is: since there are shared things then it would be a good idea to build a single module for these shared things. Rather than creating sharing mechanisms. it is?

Comment: yup - that's the basic idea.

Comment: @snorkpete, if we include one shared module in both lazy-loaded modules, does it mean that the shared module will be compiled into each lazy loaded `JS` file (into both in this case)?

Comment: What about the service for a smaller module, does both the lazy loaded modules will not get the different instances of the service if the smaller module is imported in both of them since product and brand are lazy-loaded?
If yes, what if we need the same service instance for both the lazy loaded modules?

Comment: Honestly, things have changed quite a bit since this.   There's the newer 'providedIn' config option which may give you control on where the service instance is initialised and provide more sharing options.  I've been out of the Angular dev community for some time and haven't been keeping up with the changes, so it's hard for me to advise on best practices now